# Two instances of jQuery timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have tow different jQuery functions, one is for hours and the other one for minutes.

```
$('#hour_timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h',
    interval: 1,
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
});
```

The code above works perfectly well.
However my next function, which has to show the minutes does not work,

```
$('#minute_timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'm',
    interval: 10,
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
});
```

No matter what value I select from the **minute_timepicker**, it shows completey random numbers.

Here are the inputs aswell:

```
<label id="hour_timepicker_label">Slect time</label>
<input id="hour_timepicker" type="text"/>
<label>:</label>
<input id="minute_timepicker" type="text"/>
```

Can anyone help please? Thank you.

**Link to timepicker library**: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: You'll probably need to link to the timepicker library you are using if you want to get any help

Comment: @dave I have put a link, hope that helps.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery) this plugin uses the same format as PHP's date() function, and there `m` means "Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that this library isn't really designed to pick the minutes seperately, if you had to do it you would need to set the step to 60 for hour (so it will only show in one hour increments), and then for the minutes you would need to restrict it to only show some arbitrary hour so it won't repeat, and then set the step to 10 so it will show in 10 minute increments.

```js
$('#hour_timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'H',
    interval: 1,
    step: 60,
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
});

$('#minute_timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'i',
    step: 10,
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true,
    minTime: '12:00am',
    maxTime: '12:59am'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/timepicker@1.11.14/dist/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/timepicker@1.11.14/dist/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>


<label id="hour_timepicker_label">Slect time</label>
<input id="hour_timepicker" type="text"/>
<label>:</label>
<input id="minute_timepicker" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `i` intstead of `m` on your second function.

i.e

```
$('#minute_timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'i',
    interval: 10,
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
});
```

sorry if this doesn't work.

I'm suggesting this because on the documentation, it has this:

```
$('#timeformatExample1').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i:s' });
```

`H -> hours`, `i -> minutes` and `s -> seconds`

Comment: No, sorry, it doesnt work, the values now appear to be the letter "i".

Comment: @squeekyDave hmm I see. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for that library, the timeFormat is defined as:

> timeFormat How times should be displayed in the list and input
>   element. Uses [PHP's date() formatting syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Characters can be
>   escaped with a preceeding double slash (e.g. H\hi). Alternatively,
>   you can specify a function instead of a string, to use completely
>   custom time formatting. In this case, the format function receives a
>   Date object and is expected to return a formatted time as a string.
>   default: 'g:ia'

and the PHP formatting syntax for minutes is `i`

Comment: I tried with "i",  it just shows the letter "i", even escaping the letter still shows the letter.